# Change Radio button Item class on selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using Razor view engine to generate a list of RadioButton items using this code and my css and Javascript are

```
    .radioSelection
{
    color: Green;
    font-weight: bold;        
}
 $(document).ready(function () {         
     $("input[name=ScoreId]:radio").change(function () {   
        //How can i access the label span of current selection & reset the old selection         
     });
 });

@foreach (var item in model)
{
  <li class="radio clearfix ui-sortable-handle">     
     @Html.RadioButton("ScoreId", statement_item.Id, new { @class = "" })
    <span class="lbl" >@statement_item.Statement</span>
  </li>
}
```

How can i set the class radioSelection to the selected radiobuttonList item and
Also how can i reset the selection of old item to normal when a  new radio item is choosen

Comment: `$(this).next('.lbl')` to access the associated label. Use `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` to add an remove class names. But why not use a `<label>` so its associated with the button?

Comment: This add radioSelection class to multiple items . How can i remove the other instance of radioSelection class

Comment: `$('.radioSelection').removeClass('.radioSelection');` - but call this before you add the class to the existing (or better just cache the current radio button in a js variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.next()` function to get the next element required `span`

```
$("input[name=ScoreId]:radio").change(function () { 

    $(':radio:checked').not(this).prop('checked',false)
    $('li.radioSelection').removeClass('radioSelection'); //Reset selection

    $(this).closest('li').addClass('radioSelection');   //Add class to list item

    $(this).next('span')         //Access span
});
```

Comment: Reset old selection is not working . i can see radio selection for 2 items

Answer (score 0):

Try with - `$(this).siblings('span.lbl')`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {         
  $("input[name=ScoreId]:radio").change(function () {   

  $(this).prop('checked', false); }) // make check only selected radio button and uncheck others

  $('input:radio[name=ScoreId]').each(function () {         
     $(this).removeClass('className'); })   // remove the class from all radio buttons         
  }    

  $("input:radio[name=ScoreId]:checked").closest('li').addClass('radioSelection');  // add class only to selected radio button  

  $(input:radio[name=ScoreId]:checked).next('span');         // Access span of selected radio
    });
 });
```

Comment: How about reset selection

Comment: updated the code, we are giving suggestions if working good then mark it as answer or else don't reduce the reputation or question here with clarity.

Comment: No still i can see the multiple radio  button items with same class.